# Misshapen pupil on my 5-yr old recently-adopted cat

Tags: cats, eye-disease

We recently adopted a 5-yr old cat that was surrendered to the SPCA. He was living in a sad, hoarding situation. He must have been born with his first owners because they knew his actual birthdate. He lost his eye as a young cat likely due to an infection (according to our vet). I didn't notice it right away so I am unsure if this is new, but the pupil on his remaining eye is jagged / misshapen.  What causes this? does he need treatment? Will he loose that eye too? He did pass his physical just last month, but we are concerned.

He's adjusted well here and with our other cat and we love him so much. Thanks for any info you can provide.

Comment: If your vet has already seen him, ask your vet. I would presume that if he noticed one eye was a problem he would have looked at the other.

Comment: If you want our uninformed opinions, we'd need a good photo.